# Error while updating property 'accessibilityRole' of a view managed by:RCTView

Tags: react-native

Hi I am getting following error. PFA

Error while updating property 'accessibilityRole' of a view managed by:RCTView
null
Invalid accessibility role value:tab

React Native Environment Info:

System:

```
OS: macOS 10.15.2

CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz

Memory: 53.47 MB / 8.00 GB

Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh

Binaries:

Node: 12.14.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node

npm: 6.13.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/npm

Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman

SDKs:

iOS SDK:

Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1

Android SDK:

API Levels: 28, 29

Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2

System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom

IDEs:

Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548

Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

npmPackages:

react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3

react-native: ^0.59.10 => 0.59.10
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are providing accessibilityRole worng prop.. tab should be a string..try  `accessibilityRole="tab"`

Comment: Hi, I am working on someone's code. I could not found any where in project when i search for accessibilityRole in project level. I don't know what to do...

Comment: same error, anyone fixed that ?

Comment: @NareshPalle, any solution ?

Comment: See my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70109676

Comment: See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70109676) regarding a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Use exact version of

```
"native-base":"2.13.12"
"@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
```

delete node_module and npm install

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. `cd android`
2. `gradlew clean`
3. delete the following folders (if any of them exists)
   `/android/.gradle`,
   `/android/build`,
   `/android/app/build`,